# Mikrotik L2TP тунель

Tags: vpn, mikrotik, l2tp

Есть 2 офиса,точнее один сейчас и второй делаем. 2 микротика,поднял сервер l2tp на одном и дал локалке айпишни 192.168.10.1/24,второй микротик подключаю к нему по тоннелю с локалкой 192.168.1.1/24. связь установил,на свичах пинги бегают,все норм. но из локалки 1.1 не пингуется шлюз второй локалки 192.168.10.1. я так понимаю вся беда с маскарадом.маскарад я настроил на обоих машинах,порты тоже пробросил,но связи нет. хотя к самому серверу подключался с разных компов